# UI View Partial Scrolling (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode7

I want to have a screen with some content, then a tab like interface (may be buttons, uisegment control etc.) and more content underneath it. The "more scrollable content" in the image below changes according to three btn clicks above it.

[image]

I want the user to scroll the view only till the tab buttons reach the top and then dock it there and still scroll the "more scrollable content" underneath it.

[image]

In this image, I am showing the final position of my tabs, but still the users should be able to scroll the view.

I am new to iOS and Swift. So any help (or code samples) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: just disable the scrolling OR user interaction. Change the Scroll content view using *scrollView.scrollRectToVisible* or *scrollView.setContentOffset* on button events .

Answer (score 1):

Just disable top direction scroll when scrolling to y tab frame and enable scrolling for the more scroll frame. when direction scroll get his 0 y position you must switch all : enable container scroll and disable the more scroll.

Comment: I am a bit confused. My current setup is a scroll view containing two UIViews (one for tabs and other for the bottom half of the screen with "more scrollable content"). If I disable the scrolling, both would stop scrolling. I want the user to scroll till the tabs reach the top, then if the user continues to scroll again, the tabs should stay at the top and the bottom half should continue scroll giving the tabs a floating effect